# How transform this to CQL?

Tags: c#, .net, cassandra, cql, amazon-keyspaces

I have this line, how can i reproduce it into CQL? I'm using Amazon Keyspaces which based on Cassandra.

```
DATEADD(day, @p_daysback, GETDATE());
```

Comment: So...just _what_ should this be reproduced from?  That doesn't look like valid C# syntax to me.

Comment: Reproduced from SQL

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra 4.0 supports [date/time arithmetic](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/operators.html#datetime-arithmetic) (added in [CASSANDRA-11935](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11935)), so maybe Amazon Keyspaces support it as well. Basically you either need `currentDate()` function or `cast(now() as date)` to get current date, and then add or subtract the given amount of days, like (to get back to 3 days from today):

```
currentDate() - 3d
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is doesn't work :(
currentDate() - this is also doesn't works in KeySpaces, instead of this i'm using toTimeStamp(toDate(now()), but  when i'm doing -1d i get an error:  mismatched input '-1d' expecting ')' (... toTimeStamp(toDate(now()) [-1]...)

This is my query: SELECT * FROM "transaction"."transaction_by_interfaceid"
where environment = 'Local' and interfaceid = 1 and organizationid = 1 and starttime <= toTimeStamp(toDate(now()) -1d);

Comment: then it's a limitation of amazon keyspaces... And UDF may not help you, because, at least in OSS Cassandra, there is no way to use functions in the WHERE

Comment: The date parameter needs space after the minus sign, like Alex Ott's code sample. Otherwise it throws error; "mismatched input '-1d' expecting K_FROM (SELECT toDate(now()) [-1d]...)"